# Observe or Track progress bar on every function swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, alamofire, uiprogressbar

I have implemented tableView with custom cell for appointments with progress bar for tracking. 
How can I observe or track progress bar on swift functions? Actually I am not getting exact idea how I save progress data and how to show it? I have functions hierarchy like this.

1. appointmentCall(date)

   - appointmentDetail()
   - firmDetails()
   - unitData()
   - unitDataHistory()
   - unitDataImages()
   - downloadPDFTask(pdfURL: String)

> All functions very efficiently completed but `downloadPDFTask`function takes little time for files. download PDF is using `alamofire` and have the progress only want to track it.

How I track in progress bar ?

downloadPDFTask code:

```
@objc public func downloadFile(url:String, filetype: String, callback:@escaping (_ success:Bool, _ result:Any?)->(Bool)) -> Void {
var destination = DownloadRequest.suggestedDownloadDestination(for: .documentDirectory)
if filetype.elementsEqual(".pdf"){
            destination = { _, _ in
                let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
                let downloadFileName = url.filName()
                let fileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("\(downloadFileName).pdf")
                return (fileURL, [.removePreviousFile, .createIntermediateDirectories])
            }
        } 

        self.request = Alamofire.download(
            url,
            method: .get,
            parameters: nil,
            encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
            headers: nil,
            to: destination).downloadProgress(closure: { (progress) in

                print(progress)
                print(progress.fractionCompleted)

            }).response(completionHandler: { (DefaultDownloadResponse) in
                callback(DefaultDownloadResponse.response?.statusCode == 200, DefaultDownloadResponse.destinationURL?.path)
           print(DefaultDownloadResponse)
                })
    }
```

Update Code & Image:

```
var downloadProgress : Double = 0.0 {
      didSet {
        for indexPath in self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows ?? [] {
        if let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? DownloadEntryViewCell {
            cell.individualProgress.setProgress(Float(downloadProgress), animated: true) //= "\(downloadProgress)" // do whatever you want here
            print(downloadProgress)
            }
        }
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a property observer `downloadProgress`

```
var downloadProgress : Double = 0.0 { 
    didSet { 
        self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(item: yourRow, section: 0)], with: .none) // do whatever you want here
    }
}
```

and then assign it the value of progess. `didSet` will be called every time the progress value changes.

```
    self.request = Alamofire.download(
        url,
        method: .get,
        parameters: nil,
        encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
        headers: nil,
        to: destination).downloadProgress(closure: { (progress) in

            print(progress)
            print(progress.fractionCompleted)
            self.downloadProgress = progress // assign the value here. didSet will be called everytime the progress value changes.
        }).response(completionHandler: { (DefaultDownloadResponse) in
            callback(DefaultDownloadResponse.response?.statusCode == 200, DefaultDownloadResponse.destinationURL?.path)
       print(DefaultDownloadResponse)
            })
```

Comment: Let me implement I'll get back to you.

Comment: but one thing in `didSet` mentioned `textField` but I am using tableView with custom cell.

Comment: @Newbie updated the answer. and make sure in your cellForRowAt, you are assigning your value something like this. `cell.textFielld.text = "\(downloadProgress)"`

Comment: Yes I have seen, I have implemented like this way let me update my code.

Comment: What you suggest in this ?

Comment: I am not able to understand. updated your `cellForRowAt` method code

Comment: Can I share my code with you through `github` it will be more easy to understand.

Comment: Many thanks for this, I really struggling hard for this thing. here is the link.
https://github.com/MasamMahmood/TestDownload

Comment: Is link accessible to you ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207182/discussion-between-keshu-r-and-newbie).

Answer (score 1):

You are already calling the Progress API, so the only thing you have to do is expose it to your method’s caller.

```
@objc public func downloadFile(url:String, filetype: String, updateProgress: @escaping (_ fraction: Double)->(Void), callback:@escaping (_ success:Bool, _ result:Any?)->(Bool)) -> Void {
var destination = DownloadRequest.suggestedDownloadDestination(for: .documentDirectory)
if filetype.elementsEqual(".pdf"){
            destination = { _, _ in
                let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
                let downloadFileName = url.filName()
                let fileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("\(downloadFileName).pdf")
                return (fileURL, [.removePreviousFile, .createIntermediateDirectories])
            }
        } 

        self.request = Alamofire.download(
            url,
            method: .get,
            parameters: nil,
            encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
            headers: nil,
            to: destination).downloadProgress(closure: { (progress) in

                print(progress)
                print(progress.fractionCompleted)
                // Call the update closure
                updateProgress(progress.fractionCompleted)

            }).response(completionHandler: { (DefaultDownloadResponse) in
                callback(DefaultDownloadResponse.response?.statusCode == 200, DefaultDownloadResponse.destinationURL?.path)
           print(DefaultDownloadResponse)
                })
    }
```

That way, you add a closure that receives a Double between 0 and 1 indicating the progress. In your call, you pass a closire that updates your progress bar.

Comment: Yes you are right but I am actually confused to set value on a cell. let me upload image of tableview cell.

Comment: Based on the picture that you posted, I think that the other solution will better fit what you need. I'm upvoting it.